# Boost thread condition variable three thread

Tags: c++, boost

I have a main that sets the value of two variable and wait that the two thread prints the value. Then update the value and so on...

With the main and one thread it works, but with two not.
This is my code:

```
void t(int id){

    bool block_me = true;
    while(1)
    {
        {
            boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m);
            while(!start_t || thread_executed > 0)
                start_thread.wait(lock);
        }

        // Print myself
        cout<<id<<endl;

        {
            boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m);
            thread_executed++;
            if(thread_executed == 2){
                start_main.notify_one();
            }
        }       
    }
}

int main(){

    thread_executed = 0;
    start_t = false;

    boost::thread t1(boost::bind(&t, 1));
    boost::thread t2(boost::bind(&t, 2));

    for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++){
        cout<<"i = "<<i<<endl;
        {
            boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m);  
            start_t = true;
            thread_executed = 0;
            start_thread.notify_all();  

            while(thread_executed != 2){
                start_main.wait(lock);
            }
            start_t = false;
            thread_executed = 0;
            start_thread.notify_all();
        }       
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want to signal the producer back, it's costumary to have a second condition variable. Also, access **all* shared variables only under the lock (you're violating that left and right)

Comment: Looks like you're looking for a [barrier](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.barriers)

Comment: I don't know... I need a condition for the thread to start the simpe print and a condition for the main to change the value of the "one" and "two"...

Comment: Have you considered using a message queue?

Comment: I've modified my original code... mmm, queue for??

Comment: See my answer. Not using boost but replace `std::` with `boost::` and you're using Boost Thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've modified my original code... mmm, queue for??

Let's demo it!

I generalized a little, because you basically had two single-element queues with a shared condition variable.

Much easier to reason about is two separate queues with separate conditions and locks. This, at once, untangles them for synchronization, and if you define the capacity to be > 1 the workers can have a backlog of several items queued before the main thread needs to slow down.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd700c5db6ade9ff)</kbd>**

```
#include <thread>
#include <queue>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>

static constexpr size_t queue_capacity = 1;

struct Processor {

    Processor(int id) : id_(id) {}

    void work() {
        while (running) {
            int value;
            {   // pop under lock
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mx_);
                cv_.wait(lk, [this] { return !running || !queue_.empty(); });

                if (!running)
                    break;

                // invariant: queue cannot be empty here
                value = queue_.front();
                queue_.pop();
                cv_.notify_one();
            }
            std::cout << "work " << id_ << ": " << value << "\n";
        }
    }

    void enqueue(int value) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mx_);
        cv_.wait(lk, [this] { return !running || queue_.size() < queue_capacity; });

        if (running) {
            queue_.push(value);
            cv_.notify_one();
        }
    }

    ~Processor() {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mx_);
            cv_.notify_one();
            running = false;
        }
        if (th_.joinable())
            th_.join();
    }
private:
    bool running = true;
    std::mutex mx_;
    std::condition_variable cv_;
    std::thread th_ {std::bind(&Processor::work, this)};
    int id_;

    std::queue<int> queue_;
};

int main() {
    Processor w1(1), w2(2);

    for (int i = 1; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        w1.enqueue(i*10);
        w2.enqueue(i*20);

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(150));
    }

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(4));
}
```

Prints, for example

```
work work 1: 10
2: 20
work work 2: 40
1: 20
work 2: 60
work 1: 30
work 2: 80
work 1: 40
work 2: 100
work 1: 50
work 2: 120
work 1: 60
work 2: 140
work 1: 70
work 2: 160
work 1: 80
work 2: 180
work 1: 90
```

Answer (score 1):

What is most likely to be happening here is that the first thread run and change the variable "published", and then sits and wait, the second thread just sits and waits for published to be 0 again, but that would never be the case since the main thread is waiting it to be 2 to change it back to 0.

There are few things that could be done in order to implement it in a way that works:

1. Let the threads enqueue what you need to print, and then another thread will takes things out of the queue and print them (or write them to the disk, or whatever you really need to do with them). This is quite a common pattern and would simplify the overall implementation. There may be costraint and then you may not be able to implement it this way.
2. Add "states" to your threads, so that when you are in "PRINT" state the thread would be wake and print the values, when you are in the "PROCESSING" state the thread would be waiting in the condition variable and the main thread will "process" the values. You could use [boost barriers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.barriers) to wait until all the mutexes did their job before changing the state.

A couple of suggestion:

- Don't change variable outside of mutex protection if you are reading them in the threads, the variables "published" and "termiante_thread" needs to be protected when you change them to stop the thread for instance.
- Don't use sleep, you don't need them in order to achieve a working example and they are a symptom that something is wrong in the implementation.

Comment: I've modify my original code... but, Isn't there a solution without use boost barrier??

Comment: Yes, using barrier is just one of the ways you could do it, you can look at one of the answer given that shows how you can use a queue to do it and doesn't use barriers.